# Graphics2D text draws at different position when using draw position vs translation transform

Tags: java, graphics2d

If I do this:

```
g.drawString("9", (float) 10, (float) 50);
```

the text "9" will be drawn at pixel x-position 10.

Similarly, if I do this:

```
g.translate(10, 0);
g.drawString("9", (float) 0, (float) 50);
```

the text will again be drawn at x-position 10.

However, if I do this:

```
g.translate(9.5, 0);
g.drawString("9", (float) 0.5, 50);
```

the text will appear 1 pixel to the right, presumably at x-position 11.

Here's what it looks like (zoomed in 4x) with a vertical reference line.

[image: example image]

I assume this is some kind of rounding error going on in the Graphics renderer. Is there a way to ensure the 3rd "9" draws at the same x-position as the previous two?

Comment: It looks like this may be a bug in the Graphics2D implementation in the IBM java runtime (as opposed to the Sun JRE)...

Answer (score 1):

You could round yourself your coordinates and pass to the Graphics2D only integers.